# Iterating through nested array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm working with a Twitter Rest API to gather information about trending topics.  The API returns JSON, and I'm trying to parse out the data.

Here is my relevant code (I'm not including my keys and such, etc.):

```
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings); 
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
     ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
     ->performRequest(), true);

if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") 
    {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>"
    .$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}     

foreach($string as $items)
    {
        echo "Name: ". $items['name']."<br />";
        echo "Volume: ". $items['tweet_volume']."<br /><hr />";
    }
```

What it returns is a nested array that looks kind of like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [trends] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => #NationalMargaritaDay
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23NationalMargaritaDay
                    [promoted_content] => 
                    [query] => %23NationalMargaritaDay
                    [tweet_volume] => 49400
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => #WORKvideo
                    [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23WORKvideo
                    [promoted_content] => 
                    [query] => %23WORKvideo
                    [tweet_volume] => 103959
                )
```

...and so on (I won't list the whole array).

What I need to do is be able to iterate through the [trends] array and not the parent array.  How can I modify my foreach loop to do that?  Alternatively, can I put a step or two before the for each so that I am iterating through the inside array?  I need to be able to extract the `[name]` and `[twitter_volume]` from each item.

Comment: That's the value of `$string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
foreach($string[0]['trends'] as $items) {
    ...
}
```

or if there's more than one element at the top-level of `$strings`, you need nested loops:

```
foreach ($string as $el) {
    foreach ($el['trends'] as $items) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to go the nested loop option because of some other stuff at the end of the API query.  This is a great tip for people accessing the Twitter API for trending data!  Thanks.